# Set Variables from the Matrix Field - SEO

Tags: matrix

quick question.

```
{% for block in entry.matrix %}
    {% if block.type == "seo" %}
    {% set descr = block.metaDescription %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if descr is defined %}
    <meta name="description" content="{{ descr }}" />
{% endif %}
```

meta description won't show up? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twig's `for` function is *scoped*. This means that variables defined inside of it will not be accessible outside the loop.

What you need to do, is to declare the variable with an initial value *before* the loop:

```
{% set descr = null %}

{% for block in entry.matrix %}
    {% if block.type == "seo" %}
    {% set descr = block.metaDescription %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if descr != null %}
    <meta name="description" content="{{ descr }}" />
{% endif %}
```

This works, because in Twig the inner scope (i.e. your loop) will have access to variables belonging to its parent scope, but not vice versa.